# laravel variable not assigning to session

Tags: php, laravel, session

I'm using laravel 5.5 and I have below code in my controller:

```
function booking(Request $request)
{
    parse_str($request->getContent(), $info);
    Session::put('quotation.flight.passengerDetails', $info);       
    return Session::get('quotation.flight.searchType');
}
```

This is what i have my route (**web.php**):

```
 Route::post('ajax/flight/booking', 'Flight\flightController@booking');
```

This is my ajax

```
$.ajax({
    url: flagsUrl + "ajax/flight/booking",
    type: 'POST',
    data: opts.bookingData,
    contentType: "json",
    success: function (view) {    
        opts.callback(view);    
    },
    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        opts.callback("");
    }    
});
```

When I call the route through ajax using `POST`, the `$info` doesn't assigning to the `quotation.flight.passengerDetails` session.

But it does work when I do a request using **reply XHR** in Chrome Developer Tools?

Comment: need more info which variable is not being set ?

Comment: oh it's $info variable not assigning into 'quotation.flight.passengerDetails' session

Comment: Whats the error u receive

Comment: Can you please show your AJAX code?

Comment: Where are you calling Session::save() on your execution plan?

Comment: @SmitRaval I have added my ajax. Please check

Comment: @Tschallacka I haven't used Session::save() it's not mandatory to use it right?

Comment: @Jigs1212 I don't get any error. It's not assigning the data to the session

Comment: In theory it shouldn't be mandatory. In practice, I found it resolved a LOT of the issues I had with sessions in laravel. What I usually do is make sure that ad the end of my own personal flow I call a Session::save() before outputting to the browser.

Comment: can you check if you are getting data in $info? @AroshaDeSilva

Comment: where and how are u calling the session variable ??

Comment: Also, you're not using default values. You should consider working with default values when using `Session::get('quotation.flight.searchType','retour');` that way you always get a meaningful variable back, even if it hasn't been set yet.

Comment: Also consider avoiding using magic strings for the session variables. define a few const properties in your controllers/utility classes to store the stringified values. Makes updating a storage location among many code paths much easier.

Comment: @Tschallacka i have added the Session::save()  and it did work. Thanks a lot. Can you put this as a answer so i can select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `Session::save()` after you `put()` or `push()` variables in the session object.

Usually this makes sure that the save is called when not called by any other process.

Alternatively you can analyze your execution flow and add a Session::save() at the end of your output gathering, right before your script outputs to the user, whether it be ajax or html.

For example:

```
$kernel = $app->make('Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel');
$response = $kernel->handle(
            $request = Illuminate\Http\Request::capture()
        );
\Session::save();
```

Comment: It worked like a charm. Thanks a lot for the quick support.